# Directory compression in python

Tags: python, zip, compression, shutil

I will try to explain it on example.

```
abc
├── test
    ├── dir1
    ├── dir2
    ├── not_for_zipping.txt
```

**I want to compress all directories in *test* dir (in this example it is *dir1* and *dir2*)**
Right now I made it like this:

```
    directory = dlg.lineEdit_zipfile_path2.text() // this should be path to test dir. (.../abc/test/)
    arr = os.listdir(directory)
    for item in arr:
        allfiles2zip = directory + item
        try:
            shutil.make_archive(item,'zip', + allfiles2zip)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

it looks like it is working but all directories (*dir1* and *dir2*) are compressed to: .../abc/***here***

```
abc
├── dit1.zip
├── dir2.zip
├── test
    ├── dir1
    ├── dir2
    ├── not_for_zipping.txt
```

but I would like to receive those files in selected path (directory) ...abc/test/***here***

```
abc
├── test
    ├── dir1
    ├── dir2
    ├── not_for_zipping.txt
    ├── dir1.zip
    ├── dir2.zip
```

Do you have any idea how can I change it ?
By the way, do you have any better way for this case ?

Comment: It is creating zip files in dir when app (python file is)

Comment: or maybe change directory before you start compressing - `os.chdir()` - or copy/move file after compressing - `shutil.move()` (PL: zmień katalog albo przenieś plik po kompresji)

Comment: or maybe use `make_archive('test/dir1.zip',...)`

Comment: I  made it like this: `shutil.move(item + '.zip', directory)`   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use path in file name

```
make_archive('test/' + item, 'zip', ...)
```

Eventually you can change folder before compressing

```
old_folder = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('test')
shutil.make_archive(item, 'zip', ...)
os.chdir(old_folder)
```